# How can I install on a Dell M1730 laptop?

Tags: 11.04, installation, video, laptop, dell

I currently have a Dell M1730 laptop that with the aquisition of my new system is now surplus, so thought it'd be good to throw Ubuntu on it (anything is better then the Vista currently on it).

However once I get to the menu to select "Install Ubuntu" and select a language, the screen starts blinking red, green, blue, etc.... across the whole screen in two second intervals. System boots to windows fine, and it loads the Ubuntu CD to the menu screen so it cant' be hardware related. Anyone else ran into such a strange issue, and is it compatible with this laptop?

Version is 11.04, 64bit

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you attempting to install? Please also add whether or not you're trying to install 32 or 64 bit. I have the same laptop, but have been doing upgrades to the get to updated to the last two releases.

Comment: @itnet7 I have tried both the 64 and 32bit versions with the same result happening.

Answer (score 2):

@candiancreed I had an idea of what I was planning to recommend you try, and found a post supporting my theory. You should try and use the Alternative Desktop .iso. The installation using that version is a text base (ncurses) installation and will allow you to get passed the video issues you're experiencing. I am pretty sure the problem is that the 'nv' driver has been deprecated (outdated/no longer included) in the kernel.

Once installed by that method, I would normally have recommended installing the kernel source, and nividia's drivers from their site. While trying to learn a little more about what others have done I came across an [archived ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1859869.html) in which sunsp0t described using a spare monitor hooked up to the M1730 so that the device could be logged in and the Additional drivers could be utilised to install the detected hardware drivers.

Please try this, as I feel it is your best bet. If you have any questions, or need a little further guidance with getting this accomplished leave a comment and I'll see if there is a way I can help you further.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

When you first see a brown screen during install, there should be symbol of a human and a keyboard, at this point press any key on your keyboard and you get access to a special install menu.  I think its F6-options where you can select "nomodeset" and continue install and it should work.